# How to import SVG file into After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to import an SVG animated file to an After Effects project.

It is not importing right now, so are there any solutions or any alternate ways to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you be more specific about an SVG "not importing"? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error message stating i cannot import unsupported files

Comment: Where are you saving the svg? I know that svg will work up to version 9 from illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out We cannot import svg inside HTML . so I directly used illustrator .ai file instead.

Answer (score 3):

Open in Illustrator.

Save as .ai (sorting the layers according to your needs)

Import into Ae.

Mind with the 'Import Kind' upon importing, suggest 'Composition' if you sorted the graphics into numbers of layers.

Comment: Am talking about animated SVG's

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that `.eps` files are acceptable. In my case, I own Sketch but not Illustrator so exporting `.svg` to `.eps` was more accessible than `.ai`

Also be aware when you import them they might look blurry when transforming. In order to scale properly:

Right-click the layer and hit `Create > Create Shapes From Vector Layer`

Answer (score 0):

- Open SVG File in Adobe XD
- select your paths
- Menu "File" -> "Export" -> After Effects

Now you have the paths in AE :-)